# How to clear Tasks of Google Earth Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Need help to clear Tasks of GEE(Google Earth Engine), but due to hit and trial many new tasks file has been created. Even I tried to browse any existing code but unable to find that, so please help me and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop all tasks at once by:

```
earthengine task cancel all
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel tasks by navigating to the `Tasks` tab, opening the little dropdown menu of the task (the `V` symbol), and click `Cancel`.

Alternatively, if you have the python API installed, you can list your current task list using (in a terminal):

```
earthengine task list
```

Next, copy the task IDs of the task(s) you want to cancel (one per command):

```
earthengine task cancel TASK_ID
```

Edit 20-12-2021: the GEE task manager has since been updated and now has a bulk cancel mode: https://code.earthengine.google.com/tasks.